# How to import Excel data using SQL Query (without wizard)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, matlab, odbc

Say I have thousands of Excel files with all people's information.

```
Name Height
John  182
Sam   178
...
```

If I want to import these data into a new MS-SQL database table using SQL query, how should I do that?

```
Name  Weights
John  130
Sam   160
...
```

And now if I want to append 'Weights' data into previous table using query, how should I do that?

The reason I'm doing this is because import too much Excel using wizard can lead to a huge waste of time, so I'm thinking if I can embed SQL query in MATLAB, then a for loop will do the job for me, hopefully.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [OPENROWSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) to import from excel into table

example :

```
INSERT INTO yourtable ( . . . )
SELECT  . . . 
FROM    OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
        'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\EXCEL\ExcelFile.xlsx', 
        'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```